# Как применить title() ко всем ключам словаря в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dict, словарь

```
In [5]: 'python'.title()
Out[5]: 'Python'
```

В python есть замечательный метод у строк - `title()`. Выше в примере мы видим, что он делает.

```
In [6]: d = {'python': 'guido van rossum', 'ruby': 'Yukihiro Matsumoto'}
In [7]: d
Out[7]: {'python': 'guido van rossum', 'ruby': 'Yukihiro Matsumoto'}
```

Например, у нас есть словарь.
Его ключи:

```
In [8]: d.keys()
Out[8]: dict_keys(['python', 'ruby'])
```

Каким образом я могу изменить все ключи словаря, чтобы первая их буква стала заглавной?
В результате должен получиться словарь, вида

```
In [10]: d
Out[10]: {'Python': 'guido van rossum', 'Ruby': 'Yukihiro Matsumoto'}
```

Спасибо!

Comment: `new = {k.title():v for k,v in d.items()}` ;)

Comment: `new = {k.title():d[k] for k in d}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Поскольку "нормальные" варианты уже написали в комментариях к вопросу, напишу в функциональном стиле:

```
new = dict(map(lambda kv: (kv[0].title(), kv[1]), d.items()))
```

Второй вариант:

```
new = dict(zip(map(str.title, d), d.values()))
```

Для полноты ответа все же добавлю более традиционные для Python варианты из комментариев к вопросу:

```
new = {k.title(): v for k, v in d.items()}

new = {k.title(): d[k] for k in d}
```

Comment: не поясните, а как в `str.title` заменяется `str` на элемент последовательности? Это особенность `map` (она понимает, как использовать эту функцию в такой форме записи) или более общее правило языка? Интересно, что мне интуитивно в голову пришло, что так должно работать, а потом и у вас нашел в этом примере.

Comment: @Сергей если я правильно понял вопрос, то это особенность методов в Python: первым параметром является ссылка на объект. Если метод вызывается от объекта, то объект передается как бы "сам", но можно вызывать метод от класса, и передать туда объект вручную, т.е. на строках это `"Текст".lower()` будет работать так же как и `str.lower("Текст")`, ну или обобщенно: `SomeClass().method()` работает так же, как `SomeClass.method(SomeClass())`.

Comment: Поэтому в map можно передать метод класса и последовательность объектов этого класса, и метод применится ко всем объектам, как будто метод - это обычная функция.

Comment: Верно, спасибо за отличное объяснение. Я как-то забыл, что "тип данных" и является встроенным классом (потому и люблю копаться в относительно простых задачках тут - пробелы в практических знаниях закрывают).