# Функция map написанная через def. Работа со списками имен

Tags: python, список, map

С помощью функции `map` через функцию `def` нужно вывести список имен с заглавной буквы.

Например на входе список имен:

names = ['дима', 'саша', 'костя', 'тимур']

Ожидаемый результат: ['Дима', 'Саша', 'Костя', 'Тимур']

Мой код:

```
names = ["дима", "саша", "костя", "тимур"]

def up_1():
    names_2 = []
    for i in names_2:
        return map(list(names.title()))

print(up_1())
```

Результат: `None`

Можно еще через `lambda`, но мне этот способ не подходит!

```
names = ["дима", "саша", "костя", "тимур"]
names_2 = list(map(lambda x:x.title(),names))

print(names_2)

#['Дима', 'Саша', 'Костя', 'Тимур']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ниже код с правильным использовнием `map` для задачи в вашей формулировке.

Обратите внимание, что для прямого вывода через `print`, как вы хотите,  возвращать нужно список, а не объект итератора из `map`. Ну, и используется `map` по-другому, не так как у вас в коде - см. примеры в документации.
https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/vstroennye-funktsii-interpretatora-python/funktsija-map/

```
names = ["дима", "саша", "костя", "тимур"]


def up_1():
    return list(map(str.title, names))


print(up_1())
```

Comment: Вот, кстати, схожий полезный пример ответа от @insolor для ознакомления: <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032489/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-title-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%B2-python>

Comment: Ответ как бы и правильный, спору нет. Вот только зачем оборачивать list(map(str.title, names)) в бессмысленную обертку? Вопрос не к уважаемому Сергею, а к преподавателю - ну должны же даже элементарные задания иметь какой-то хоть тоже элементарный смысл?

Answer (score 2):

А причем тут map?

```
names = ["дима", "саша", "костя", "тимур"]
def up_1(names):
    names_2 = []
    for item in names:
        names_2.append(item.title())
    return names_2 

print(up_1(names))
```

Результат:

```
['Дима', 'Саша', 'Костя', 'Тимур']
```

P.S. Кстати, выражение "Функция.... написанная через def"  - это круто! Предполагаю, что вас просто попросили написать функцию, которая будет работать аналогично функции map. Вот это я вам и показал.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/V2VyKqVCBXLyxm       Видимо я не так понял задание

Comment: Правильно вы поняли задание - см. мой ответ.

Comment: @passant, по вашему вопросу "причем тут map?" - с ней просто короче код - одна строка и цикл самому делать не надо:-) См. мой ответ. (ну и просто задание такое у автора вопроса). Впрочем, полагаю, вы это лучше меня знаете в разы:-)